# How To Use Variable For Driver In C# Using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to use different IWebDrivers For My Method. For that I use different public IWebDrivers. So far no problem. However I would like to use a variable whenever I for example want to search for a specific element.

For Illustration: `driver.Navigate.GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");`  So, how would I know use a not yet defined variable? In my method I will use an if statement in connection with an else if statement, so depending on which if statement is used, a specific driver should be used.

For Illustration: `if (...) a = driver1  else if (...) a = driver2`. Since the driver would only defined whenever one of the if-statements or if-else statements has been initialized, it tells me that I can't use .Navigate with a. Is there a way to solve this? Otherwise I would have a lot of duplicate code

Comment: To clarify your question, you want to use different web drivers, but some part of your code needs to decide which driver to use? For example, if some condition, use GeckoDriver, else if something else, use ChromeDriver?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the code you have already tried? Maybe you are close to the solution.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant

Comment: As written I tried to use a variable for the drivers. So that I say var a = driver1. But it does not work. it says there is not Navigate() method for it, since if I don't explicitly define it at application start, it seems to be "confused", for the lack of a better word.

Comment: Without seeing the code you have tried, it is difficult to give you a specific solution. Can you [edit] your question to include what you tried? Basically you need to use the [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#) to decide at runtime which specific web driver you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly it may help to pack your drivers into a list and reference to the one you want. Something like this:

```
        ChromeDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
        EdgeDriver driver2 = new EdgeDriver();

        IWebDriver[] drivers = new IWebDriver[2];
        drivers[0] = driver1;
        drivers[1] = driver2;

        int driverToUse;

        if (true)
        {
            driverToUse = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            driverToUse = 1;
        }

        drivers[driverToUse].Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: This works perfectly in my scenario. I appreciate the time you have invested in answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#) is a software design pattern that allows you to defer initialization of an object until runtime, where based on some condition you return different concrete implementations of an abstract class or interface. You might be able to use this pattern to decouple the initialization of specific web drivers from the code that needs to automate the browser.

Typically you need a class or just a method to make this decision. The example below uses a class, but you can put the `CreateWebDriver` method in any class that you want.

```
public class WebDriverFactory
{
    public IWebDriver CreateWebDriver(string driverType)
    {
        switch (driverType.ToLower())
        {
            case "firefox":
                return new GeckoDriver();
            case "chrome":
                return new ChromeDriver();
            case "edge":
                return new EdgeDriver();
            case "opera":
                return new OperaDriver();
            case "internet explorer":
                // fall through
            case "ie"
                return new InternetExplorerDriver();
            case "safari":
                return new SafariDriver();
        }
    }
}
```

To use this factory object:

```
var factory = new WebDriverFactory();

var driver = factory.CreateWebDriver("chrome");

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");
```

Since you do not have any code in your question, I cannot recommend a way to share this web driver object with the rest of your automation code. If you update your question with the code that you have, I can update my answer to figure out how to reuse this driver object in multiple tests or use cases.

Comment: I can't yet give any up-votes, because I still need to have at least 15 reputation. I tried your solution first but quickly resized after trying the solution of @r000bin that answer of that person, was more optional for my scenario.